# Relationship between Product of $L^p$ spaces an product measures

Tags: integration, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and $(Y,\Gamma,\nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces.  Is there a relationship between $L^p_{\mu}(\Sigma)\times L^p_{\nu}(\Gamma)$, equipped with the product of their $L^p$-topologies, and the space $L^p_{\mu\otimes \nu}(\Sigma \otimes \Gamma)$?

More generally, let $(X_i,\Sigma_i,\mu_i)$ be a countably infinite familly of $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, then is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} L_{\mu}^p(\Sigma_i) \mbox{ dense in } L^p_{\bigotimes_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu_i}\left(\bigotimes_{i=1}^{\infty}\Sigma_i\right)?
$$

---

**Ideas and Update:**

Initially, my intuition was (as noted in the comment below) to pass through the completed injective tensor product $L_{\mu}^p(\Sigma)\otimes_{\epsilon} L^p_{\nu}(\Gamma)$.

Though now I doubt that works since according to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336970/the-norm-of-tensor-product-operator-on-lp-spaces) and some results of Grothendieck, if $p=1$ then $L_{\mu}^p(\Sigma)\otimes_{\epsilon} L^p_{\nu}(\Gamma)\cong L_{\mu}^p(X;L_{\nu}^p(\Gamma))$ (the Pettis-Gel'fand integrable functions).

Comment: what have you tried? do you have any conjectures?

Comment: I conjecture that $L_{\mu}^p(\Sigma)\times L_{\nu}^p(\Gamma)$ is dense in $L^p_{\mu\otimes \nu}(\Sigma\otimes \Gamma)$ and that the later is linearly-isomorphic to the completed injective tensor product $L_{\mu}(\Sigma)\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon} L_{\nu}^p(\Gamma)$... but this is just intuition and I've been stuck otherwise.  I tried to used some Fubini-type result but nothing...

Comment: If $(f,g)\in L^p_\mu\times L^p_\nu$, then let
$$
\Phi(f,g)(x,y):=f(x)·g(y)
$$
By Fubini, $\Phi(f,g)\in L^p_{\mu\otimes \nu}$ 

Suppose now that $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces. Letting
$$
\mathcal{A}:=\Phi[C(X)\times C(Y)]\subset C(X\times Y)
$$
it is routine to check that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of functions which separates points of $X\times Y$. By the Stone-Weiestrass theorem, $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C(X\times Y) $ wrt $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. This in turn implies that $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $L^p_{\mu\otimes\nu}$ wrt $\|\cdot\|_p$.

Comment: @Reveillark Interesting, so this would work but only granted that we have finite products.  That is, $\prod_{i=1}^n C(X_i)$ is dense in $L_{\mu_1\otimes \dots \otimes \mu_n}^p$, wrt $\|\cdot\|_p$ but I guess $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} C(X_i)$ would not be dense some in $L^p_{\otimes_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu_i}$ (or would it)?